# Using str.replace in a for loop without losing last iteration

Tags: c#, algorithm, for-loop

So currently I am working on a piece of code where I am given a string and need to count how many times each character in the string appears and if it appears only once replace it with a x and if it appears more than once replace it with a y. EG: "Scores" => "yxxxxy".

my current code is

```
    public static string changeWord(string word)
    {
        var Pl = word;
        var pj = Pl;
        string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
        {
            var count = word.Count(x => x == alpha[i]);
            Console.WriteLine(count);

            if (count > 1)
            {
                Pl = word.Replace(alpha[i], 'y');
            }
            else if (count == 1)
            {
                Pl = word.Replace(alpha[i], 'x');
            }
        }

        return Pl;
    }
```

The count works and shows the the correct count for each letter but only changes the last one in the code so "Please" => "Pleaxe" I don't know how to get .replace to keep my new string.

Comment: On each iteration, you start with the value in `word`. The value in `word` is never changed. You only assign the result of the replacement to `Pl`, you don't assign the result of the replacement to `word`.

Comment: `Pl = Pl.Replace(alpha[i], 'y');`

Comment: You need to replace on Pl , not word.

Comment: Pl = Pl.Replace(alpha[i], 'y'); and same with x

Comment: Unrelated: `pj` does not seem to be used anywhere?

Comment: Another point is that your sample indicates that case should be ignored (the S and the s are counted as the same) but your code does not ignore case.

Comment: @MatthewWatson good point It should thank you

Comment: @Fildor Yeah sorry I was just fiddling with the code and accidently left that in.

Comment: You loop through the alphabet and change all letters to an 'x' or 'y'. But you encounter those as final letters in that alphabet, so this would change the changed letters again (when you fix the re-assignment to 'word')!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem `Replace` algorithm: once converted letter to `x` you then should process letter `x` itself, e.g.

```
initial:              box

after 'b' processed:  xox
after 'o' processed:  xxx # note, that x appeared 3 times now
after 'x' processed:  yyy
after 'y' processed:  yyy # we have 3 y's so they changed to themselves 

finally:              yyy # when xxx is expected
```

That's why instead of changing existng `word`, I suggest using `StringBuilder` and *build* the *new* string:

```
    public static string changeWord(string word) {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
        return word;

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);

      for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; ++i)
        if (sb[i] >= 'a' && sb[i] <= 'z')
          sb[i] = word.Count(c => c == sb[i]) > 1 ? 'y' : 'x';

      return sb.ToString();
    }
```

In case of *long* `word`, too many `Count` can be time consuming; you can try *caching* them:

```
    public static string changeWord(string word) {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
        return word;

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);

      Dictionary<char, int> counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

      for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; ++i)
        if (sb[i] >= 'a' && sb[i] <= 'z') {
          if (!counts.TryGetValue(sb[i], out int count)) {
            count = word.Count(c => c == sb[i]);

            counts.Add(sb[i], count);
          }

          sb[i] = count > 1 ? 'y' : 'x';
        }

      return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static string changeWord(string word)
        {
            string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

            for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
            {
                var count = word.Count(x => x == alpha[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(count);

                if (count > 1)
                {
                    word = word.Replace(alpha[i], 'y');

                }
                else if (count == 1)
                {
                    word = word.Replace(alpha[i], 'x');

                }
            }

            return word;
        }
```

Comment: Counter example: `box`: expected `xxx`, actual: `yyy`

Answer (score 0):

This method  makes the job you want

```
public static string changeWord(string word)
    {
        var wordToEdit = word;
        string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
        {
            var count = word.Count(x => x == alpha[i]);

            if (count > 0)
            {
                wordToEdit = wordToEdit.Replace(alpha[i], count == 1 ? 'x' : 'y');
            }
        }

        return wordToEdit;
    }
```